# What is my correct url path to the API restful with node.js & express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I have two routes in my restful api with node.js and express.

The first route is:

```
http://localhost:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=4&daysForward=3
```

and work fine !

I try to see the data from second route, but I see this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id2' of undefined
```

when I enter this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/stations?id2=1010
```

The code:

```
  app.route('/stations')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    const id2 = req.query.id2;
      const query2 = `SELECT Station,Ime FROM aladin_surfex.stations_cells WHERE Station=${id2}`;
      con.query(query2, function (err, result2, fields) {
        if (err) 
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error"})
        aladinModelStations = result2;
        res.json({ aladinModelStations })
      })
  });
```

So I think the mistake is in this line:

```
const id2 = req.query2.id2;
```

When I replace query2 with query:

```
const id2 = req.query.id2;
```

I see empty aladinModelStations "" without erros, but Im 100% sure where I enter id2=1010 - that there should be data.

Im not sure how to be correct because I have query in the first route and query2 in the second ?

And what is my correct path to see values on the api from my second path ?

Comment: `req.query2` is wrong and doesn't exist, hence the error in the title. With `req.query2` there is a different issue, but I am not sure which. Can you try using a different name for the `id2` parameter, without numbers?

Comment: @Pizhev Racing after replacing to `const id2 = req.query.id2;` whether `id2` is printed??

Comment: this is not relevant to your question, but the code you posted contains a security vulnerability (if it worked): Arbitrary data can be added to your SQL query. You should not be simply adding user strings into a SQL query, instead use this feature or prepared statements: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

You must use [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query):

> This property is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it is the empty object, {}.

**2.**

> When I replace query2 with query:
>
> ```
> const id2 = req.query.id2;
> ```
>
> I see empty aladinModelStations "" without erros,

If you look at the first route you have set `aladinModel` : `aladinModel = result`, you must do the same thing for `aladinModelStations`:

```
const aladinModelStations = result2;
res.json({ aladinModelStations })
```

Or

```
res.json({ aladinModelStations: result2 })
```

**3.**

As stated in the `req.query`'s doc and by *@sol*'s comment **you should never trust user input**

> As req.query’s shape is based on user-controlled input, all properties and values in this object are untrusted and should be validated before trusting.

You could [escape it](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#escaping-query-identifiers) using `connection.escapeId()` for example:

```
const query2 = `SELECT Station,Ime FROM aladin_surfex.stations_cells WHERE Station=${connection.escapeId(id2)}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `const id2 = req.query2.id2;` for the route `/stations` but it should be `const id2 = req.query.id2;`. Because there is no any property called `query2` in the `req` object. Thus, you get that error since, `req.query2` is itself undefined and you cannot get the `id2` value from the undefined value. And hence the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id2' of undefined

Comment: The question states that he tried that also and he is facing some other issue

Answer (score 1):

The variable `aladinModelStations` is not assigned with `result2`